# Is there any way to get the first 10 from the list of objects in APEX?

Tags: apex, list

I need to get the first 10 object from the list that comes from the Query without limiting in the query

```
notifs = [SELECT id FROM Notification__c 
                      WHERE Read__c=false ORDER BY Start__c DESC];
```

like in javascript i can use slice(0, 10),is there any way to get the sublist in APEX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a regular for cycle iterating the first 10 results. Please be sure to validate that the list returns at least 10 results, otherwise you may run into a *System.ListException: List index out of bounds* exception.

Please find the example code for what you're trying to achieve:

```
List<Notification__c> notifs = [SELECT id FROM Notification__c WHERE Read__c=false ORDER BY Start__c DESC]; 

if(notifs.size()>=10){
    for(Integer i=0; i<=9; i++){
        System.debug(i + ': ' + notifs[i].Id);
    }
}
```

Best regards!

Comment: thanks,it worked. 
but i found that there are no predefined method in APEX to get a sub list or slice the list

Comment: @Arzad That's correct.

Comment: Getting up to 10 is as easy as: `while(!notifs.isEmpty() && otherList.size() < 10) { otherList.add(notifs.remove(notifs)); }` or `for(Integer i = 0, s = Math.min(10, otherList.size()), i < s; i++) { System.debug(notifs[i]); }`